# Is it possible to define the generic type from a derived type reference?

Tags: c#

I am not sure how to word my title but i am trying to create a struct that is generic, and i want the generic type to be defined by the reference i pass in.

So for example with pseudo code:

```
public struct Packet <T>
{
    public ITest<T> Object;          
}
```

So now lets say i have the class:

```
public class SomeObject : ITest<float>
```

I would like to assign `SomeObject` to the Packet without having to actually type `<float>` in the code so it is more dynamic.

Some pseduo code example of what i would like the functionality to do:

```
Packet packet = new Packet(SomeObject); // would now be Packet<float> type
```

Would then mean the packet is a `Packet<float>` because the class inherits the interface that has been set to float.

Is this possible ? If so how would you do it ?

Comment: Maybe? Basically i don't want to have to manually say <float> as the type it should be able to determine it from the class and the type it inherits? I'll write a pseudo example of what i'd like to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type inference doesn't work for constructors, so you'd need a factory method for this:

```
public static class PacketFactory {
    public static Packet<T> FromITest<T>(ITest<T> itest) {
        var packet = new Packet<T>();
        packet.Object = itest;
        return packet;
    }
}
```

Now you can create your packets without `<float>`:

```
var packet = PacketFactory.FromITest(new SomeObject());
```

Comment: Ah nice thats a neat way to do it ! Thanks :)